# Exporting multiple access tables and removing carriage returns/ line breaks

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am creating an automated process that exports 50 tables I have in access to a CSV. The issue I'm having is one row in a table has carriage returns or line breaks mixed in. When I open the exported CSVs as a text file, some lines are broken up.

The data type for the troublesome row are all text. I need help integrating a statement in my VBA script to remove the spaces in front of any characters & remove any line breaks or carriage returns as well.

There is only one column in this one table giving me issues.

I have tried Trim & Replace statements that don't seem to work. It could be caused from not writing them correctly.

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExportDatabaseObjects()
On Error GoTo Err_ExportDatabaseObjects

    Dim db As Database
    Dim td As TableDef
    Dim d As Document
    Dim c As Container
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sExportLocation As String

    Set db = CurrentDb()

    sExportLocation = "C:\File Path\"

For Each td In db.TableDefs 'Tables
    If Left(td.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
        CurrentDB.execute " UPDATE " & td.Name & " SET yourColumn='" & REPLACE(yourColumn, CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), "") & "' WHERE INSTR(1, yourColumn, CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))>0"
        DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , td.Name, sExportLocation & "Table_" & td.Name & ".csv", True
    End If
Next td
Set db = Nothing
    Set c = Nothing

    MsgBox "All database objects have been exported as a csv file to " & sExportLocation, vbInformation

Exit_ExportDatabaseObjects:
    Exit Sub

Err_ExportDatabaseObjects:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_ExportDatabaseObjects

End Sub
```

My VBA script successfully exports all tables in my access database into the folder I want. Now I need some help cleaning up the data before it goes into production.

Comment: There is no Trim/Replace in this.. would be nice to see what you have tried already.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you mean with _"to remove the spaces in front of any characters"_. If this is what you want, then it would turn your comment into this: _"toremovethespacesinfrontofanycharacters"_.

Comment: You either have to modify data in table or export a query that fixes the values.

Comment: I need help writing this replace or trim statement. I don"t know exactly how to write it or where to put it in my VBA script above. Some values in this problematic include: "t " or  " ab" or "b with a carriage return"

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each td In db.TableDefs 'Tables
    If Left(td.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
        CurrentDB.execute " UPDATE " & td.Name & " SET yourColumn='" & REPLACE(yourColumn, CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), "") & "' WHERE INSTR(1, yourColumn, CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))>0"
        DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , td.Name, sExportLocation & "Table_" & td.Name & ".csv", True
    End If
Next td
```

This should help you find and replace bad characters

Comment: ^^ Would that go in my VBA script? If so, where?

Comment: @ZZEE, backup your table and try the UPDATE statement provided by Doug first. In order to get rid of leading and trailing spaces, write another UPDATE statement using the TRIM function.

Comment: @ZZEE That depends on hwo you want to handle it. This is just SQL but its the easiest way to get rid of line breaks in your column value sin the tables. Ill update the answer to show you how to do it for each table.

Comment: Keep in mind, you'll need to alter this if you want to hit more than 1 column.

Comment: I added the update and replace query Doug provided into my VBA Script, it is giving me a syntax error. I replaced the yourColumn with my column name. Do i need to specify the table name somewhere?

Comment: I just changed the tb.name to tb.name of my table. now access is telling me method or data member not found on that table. Ideas?

Comment: no you shouldnt have to - the td.name is pulling the table name dynamically.

Comment: Ok. So i added your answer provided to my VBA script between For "Each tb" through "Next tb". I changed all the "YourColumn" to the name of the column in the table. When i go to run the entire VBA script, I'm getting a syntax error on the "3075 - syntax error in string in query expression 'REPLACE(.......

Comment: @ZZEE OK I see where i messed up - the replace function had to be escaped form the sql string. Keep in mind if the source data in the table is a string you'll need single quotes as well. if not just remove them

Comment: @Doug Coats now i am getting a "Variable not defined error". I took your updated code, replaced every "YourColumn" with the name of my table. Any ideas of why it's giving me this error? What am i missing? Thank you for all your help thus far!

Comment: @ZZEE you should replace every "YourColumn" with your column name.

Comment: So i just updated the query in my question with the code @DougCoats suggested. I replaced all "YourColumn" with the name of the column that is giving me a hard time. I am getting a "Compile Error: Variable not defined" and it's highlighting my column name. I read this has to do with not explicitly declaring all variables? I'm sure it's a simple thing i'm missing now.